# Symfony 2. Sorting an array by DateTime

Tags: symfony, sorting, datetime

Arrays of data:

```
    $allEvents = [];        
    foreach ($events as $event) {
            $allEvents[] = $event;
    }
    foreach ($user->getEvents() as $event) {
            $allEvents[] = $event;
    }
```

Result to twig:

```
        return $this->render(
        'MyBundle:User:dashboard.html.twig',
        [   'allEvents' => $allEvents,
            'user' => $user   ]
        );
```

var_dump allEvents result:

```
array:5 [ 0 => Event {
                 id: 26
                 title: "test action"
                 category: Category
                 creator: User
                 ***schedule***: DateTime {
                      "date": "2015-12-24 17:10:00.000000"
                      "timezone_type": ...
                      "timezone": ...
                      }
                 }
          1 => Event {...}
          2 => Event {...}
          3 => Event {...}
          4 => Event {...} 
        ]
```

Question: How can I do sort an array by **schedule** (some like sort by ASC or DESC)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the usort function of PHP as below (I've edited the answer for you to see clearer):

**EDIT:**

```
$allSortedEvents = usort( $allEvents, function( $a, $b ){
    if ( $a->getSchedule() == $b->getSchedule() )
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return ( $a->getSchedule() < $b->getSchedule() ) ? -1 : 1;
    }
});
```

And send to Twig as:

```
return $this->render(
    'MyBundle:User:dashboard.html.twig',
    [   'allEvents' => $allSortedEvents,
        'user' => $user   ]
    );
```

Comment: tried it. error: 'warning: usort() expects parameter 2 to be a valid callback, function 'customSort' not found or invalid function name'. have another idea?

Comment: Where did you write the customSort function?

Comment: Solution: `$a["schedule"]` replaced on `$a->getSchedule()` and others